# Flutter: How can I navigate to a screen with page turn / page curl effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, effects

**how to make a Page Curl effect in a Flutter app as in this photo**

- I tried this package but it renders the screen as an image So can not interact with the screen as usual.
  https://github.com/fluttercommunity/page_turn

[image]

Comment: Try this https://pub.dev/packages/better_page_turn

Comment: Thanks, Tejaswini
I have tried it, Works well with pages like an Ebook
But I need to make the left to right page turn when I navigate normally to a new screen.

Answer (score 0):

I used the *Flip_Widget* package.

I would navigate from splash to home screen, as below:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flip_widget/flip_widget.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

const double _MinNumber = 0.008;
double _clampMin(double v) {
  if (v < _MinNumber && v > -_MinNumber) {
    if (v >= 0) {
      v = _MinNumber;
    } else {
      v = -_MinNumber;
    }
  }
  return v;
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  late Timer _timer;

  _goNext() async {
    _flipKey.currentState?.startFlip();

    List<double> percent = [
      0.1,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.4,
      0.5,
      0.6,
      0.7,
      0.8,
    ];
    List<double> tilt = [
      1.0,
      1.5,
      2.0,
      2.0,
      3.0,
      -13,
      -16,
      -20,
    ];

    for (int i = 0; i < percent.length; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

      _flipKey.currentState?.flip(percent[i], tilt[i]);
    }
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.home);
  }

  _startDelay() {
    _timer = Timer(
        const Duration(seconds: AppConstants.splashDelay), () => _goNext());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startDelay();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  GlobalKey<FlipWidgetState> _flipKey = GlobalKey();
  Offset _oldPosition = Offset.zero;
  bool _visible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = Size(100.w, 100.h);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorManager.bgColor,
        body: Container(
          color: ColorManager.bgColor,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: FlipWidget(
              leftToRight: true,
              key: _flipKey,
              rollSize: 30,
              child: yourWidget(),
            
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```